# Set button attributes via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

Need to set some attributes of button. For example "Checked". I guess it is plain, but I can't handle with it. Please give peace of advice.

```
 Html.DevExpress().Button(
                   btnSettings =>
                   {
                       btnSettings.Name = "Details";
                       btnSettings.Text = "";
                       btnSettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function (s,e){Details.Checked = true}";
                       btnSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
                       btnSettings.ToolTip = "details";
                       btnSettings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                       btnSettings.AllowFocus = false;
                       btnSettings.Width = 1;
                       btnSettings.Height = 1;
                   }
               )
               .Render();
```

Comment: Do you need to set it on server or client side?

Comment: How do you want to make a **Button** checked? There is no `checked` attribute for a button unless it is radio or check box.

Comment: @Yo-ho-ho: As what html element does the `Button` render on the web page?

Comment: DevExpress button has attribute "Checked". But it is not necessary in this case. Even if I'm trying to set "function (s,e){Details.Disabled = true}"; it also doesn't work

Comment: @Răzvan Panda: <td></td>. table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [devexpress online docu](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9011)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function button1_CheckedChanged(s, e) {
        if (s.GetChecked()) {
            button2.SetEnabled(false);
            s.SetText("Enable Button");
        } else {
            button2.SetEnabled(true);
            s.SetText("Disable Button");
        }
    }
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <% 
                Html.DevExpress().Button(
                    settings => {
                        settings.Name = "button1";

                        settings.Text = "Disable Button";
                        settings.Width = 120;
                        settings.GroupName = "FakeGroup";
                        settings.ClientSideEvents.CheckedChanged = "button1_CheckedChanged";
                    }
                )
                .Render();
            %>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <% 
                Html.DevExpress().Button(
                    settings => {
                        settings.Name = "button2";
                        settings.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
                    }
                )
                .Render();
            %>        
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```